# Issue with Linguex package in chapters

Tags: linguex

I'm having some issues with Linguex package when I want to use \ex. in other chapters in my document. It shows me this error:

`./EncabezadoTesisMSc.tex:100:
Runaway argument?
 \a . John es inglés pero es temperamental \b . inglés(john) $\wedge \ETC.
File ended while scanning use of \ex.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.100 \include{Kap3/Kap3}`

So I look over ./EncabezadoTesisMsc.tex:100 and look arround for any troubles in the code. But there's no issue because I already used the linguex package in the prevoius chapter: `kap2/kap2`

I'm going to copy and paste the relevant code from the preamble.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,spanish,fleqn,openany,letterpaper,pagesize]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[]{linguex}


\usepackage{Befehle}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{HojaTitulo/HojaTituloMSc}


    {\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Kap1/Kap1}
\include{Kap2/Kap2}
\include{Kap3/Kap3}
\include{Kap4/Kap4}
\include{Kap5/Kap5}

\end{document}
```

In Kap3.tex file I just try to use and then appears the error.

```
\chapter{this is chapter 3}
\ex. some example
```

Comment: Please add the *really relevant* parts. Apparently the error occurs in `Kap3/Kap3.tex`. Please make sure that the code that you post does not refer to files that are not available to us. Either they are irrelevant, then remove the corresponding `\include`. If they are relevant (the error depends on the file), then include the file or parts of it.

Comment: I think it doesn't matters. I mean, the document has diferent _files_, when I use `\ex.` on file kap3.tex it says the error is in kap3/kap3 which is in `/EncabezadoTesisMSc.tex:100` where's the preamble. By the way, I'm going to add the file in the code. Excuse me.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't matter"? If I comment out all your includes, the code that you have posted compiles. We need sample code that produces the error otherwise we don't know what we are looking for. Remove all the includes and copy as much of the stuff as needed from the files to the main file such that the error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You need an empty line to terminate the argument of `\ex`.

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{linguex}
\begin{document}
\ex. some example

\end{document}
```

This does not, but gives the error `File ended while scanning use of \ex.`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{linguex}
\begin{document}
\ex. some example
\end{document}
```

Here is a longer example; note the empty lines.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{linguex}
\begin{document}
\ex. First item
\a. First sub-item of first item
\b. Second sub-item of first item
\a. First sub-sub-item of second sub-item of first item
\b. Second sub-sub-item of second sub-item of first item

\ex. Second item
\a. First sub-item of second item
\b. Second sub-item of second item
\a. First sub-sub-item of second sub-item of second item
\b. Second sub-sub-item of second sub-item of second item

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works. My bad.